# Array Indices Syms Error when running code

Tags: matlab

```
clear;
clc;

m=18;
L=4;
g=9.81;

syms ax alpha ay na nb
S = solve(ax - .5.*L.*alpha.*cos(30)==0, 0 ==(ax + alpha.*L.*.5.*cos(30)).*sin(20) + (ay + alpha.*.5.*L.*sin(30)).*cos(30), na + nb.*sin(20) == m.*ax, nb.*cos(20) - m.*g == m.*ay, -na(L./2.*cos(30)) + nb.*cos(20).*(L./2.*sin(30)) + nb.*sin(20).*(L./2.*cos(30)) == .5.*m.*L.^2.*alpha);

S = [S.ax, S.alpha, S.ay, S.na, S.nb]
```

keep getting Array indices must be positive integers or logical values error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script needed a multiplication sign proceeding `-na` in the `solve()` line. Try this snippet below:

```
clear;
clc;

m=18;
L=4;
g=9.81;

syms ax alpha ay na nb
S = solve(ax - .5.*L.*alpha.*cos(30)==0, 0==(ax + alpha.*L.*.5.*cos(30)).*sin(20) + (ay + alpha.*.5.*L.*sin(30)).*cos(30), na + nb.*sin(20) == m.*ax, nb.*cos(20) - m.*g == m.*ay, -na.*(L./2.*cos(30)) + nb.*cos(20).*(L./2.*sin(30)) + nb.*sin(20).*(L./2.*cos(30)) == .5.*m.*L.^2.*alpha);
S = [S.ax, S.alpha, S.ay, S.na, S.nb];
disp(S);
```